# No MODS button in Windows Minecraft when selecting Forge profile

Tags: minecraft-modding

I have installed a Minecraft launcher in Windows that supports Minecraft 1.14. I have installed Forge 1.14.4-forge-28.0.13. I have created the mods folder and placed a mod jar in it which is Xaeros_Minimap_1.17.4_Forge_1.14.4.

I have selected the Forge profile in the launcher. When running the launcher, I have to remove JVM option -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode in order to run it (also when running the regular profile). I have Java 11 installed.

But after launching, there is no MOD button in the menu. What could be the problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about troubleshooting a game, not developing one

Comment: I'll agree with Bálint here. It's not clear if you're trying to play the game with a mod, or if you're trying to actual develop the mod.

Comment: I was advised to post my question here when I first posted it at https://gaming.stackexchange.com as it was closed there for being off-topic. These forums are not of much help. Never mind.